# OpenCV and a description coordinates of the figures

Tags: c#, opencv

Task:

- Сamera is focused on the wall
- Information from the camera is read in real time
- Figures are hanging on a white wall
- It is necessary to discover figures and transfer them to their contours for further processing

Problems:

- I can't create a mask that doesn't deform the figure:

  > I used to create the mask: Cv2.Canny, Cv2.Threshold.Finding the parameter is difficult so in each
  > image I calculate the meridian and use the [confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) that spans 66%(if you're curious, I used the
  > Trackbar, but it still took time to adjust the papameters). I've used a lot of ways to create a
  > suitable mask so I have an obscene amount of code. So I'll just leave the code for finding the meridian.

  ```
   public static double Median(Mat imgMat)
   {
       double m = (imgMat.Rows * imgMat.Cols) / 2;
       int bin = 0;
       double med = -1.0;

       Mat hist = new Mat();
       int[] hdims = { 256 };
       Rangef[] ranges = { new Rangef(0, 256), };
       Cv2.CalcHist(
           new Mat[] { imgMat },
           new int[] { 0 },
           null,
           hist,
           1,
           hdims,
           ranges);

       for (int i = 0; i < hdims[0] && med < 0.0; ++i)
       {
           bin += (int)hist.At<float>(i);

           if (bin > m && med < 0.0)
           {
               med = i;
           }
       }

       return med;
   }
  ```
- Only the important points of the shape need to be found, so I use approximation.Since the points
  describing the figures are moving, the very outline of the figure itself also moves (If I use a
  different approximator, then the results are also not correct). My observations:

  > Cv2.ApproxPolyDP - moves too much 
  > Cv2.ConvexHull - describes well the entire area occupied by the points, but poorly describes the
  > shape

---

```
public class ConvexHull : IApproxPoints
{
    private double perimeterLimit;

    public ConvexHull(double perimeterLimit)
    {
        this.perimeterLimit = perimeterLimit;
    }
    public Point[][] ApproxPoints(Point[][] points)
    {
        LinkedList<Point[]> vectorApproxPoints = new LinkedList<Point[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            double perimeter = Cv2.ArcLength(points[i], true);
            if (perimeter > perimeterLimit)
            {
                Point[] approxPoints = Cv2.ConvexHull(points[i], false);
                vectorApproxPoints.AddLast(approxPoints);
            }
        }
        return vectorApproxPoints.ToArray();
    }
}
```

---

Please write any of your solutions or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to calculate common elements on several masks. So I can get rid of noise and unnecessary movement when approximating

---

```
public class CleanFrame
{
    private Queue<Mat> frames = new Queue<Mat>();
    private int limitOfFrame;

    public CleanFrame(int limitOfFrame = 25)
    {
        this.limitOfFrame = limitOfFrame;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// put a frame mask in the queue for processing
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="frame">frame mask</param>
    /// <returns>common elements on all frame masks</returns>
    public Mat PushFrame(Mat frame)
    {
        if (frames.Count == limitOfFrame)
        {
            frames.Dequeue();
        }
        frames.Enqueue(frame);
        return GetCommonElements();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// processes masks and returns common elements
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Mat GetCommonElements()
    {
        Mat result = frames.Peek();

        foreach (var frame in frames)
        {
            Cv2.BitwiseAnd(result,frame,result);
            Cv2.ImShow("result", result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

---

but it could be better